# Switch to Previous & Next cell on IQKeyboard manager up and down button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, iqkeyboardmanager

I'm using IQKeyboard Manager in my project, In my project I have one screen with a similar design to an Excel sheet. Check Image

Let me explain you in details so it's easy to understand problem. App will connect with the Bluetooth laser device and that device take reading and paste on the app, That device also switch the text textfield automatically by tabbing functionality `(Switch to next text field)`

So I used tableview in my app, You can see the horizontal line which indicate `tableview cell` in tableview cell I have multiple `textfields` you can see in the image.

To understand issue I add numbers for each textfield so I can explain easily.

Now let's say currently `textfield 1` is active and laser device will take reading and paste value in that textfield, Once the text is set in textfield it's switch to next textfield which is `textfield 2` and so on.

Now what I want is, Instead of `textfield 2` I want `textfield 11` to `becomeFirstResponder()` which is a next tableview cell, Until last row. On last row it again to first `cell` and active next text field which is `textfield 2`.

In short it's travel vertically instead of horizontally, Can you please help us like how can we achieve this? I haven't done any special coding just use `tableview` and `IQKeyboard` so I'm not attaching any code here, If you still think you need code I'm happy to edit question.

[image]

[image]